# Searching Tracks Spotify Android

Tags: android, spotify

I am currently able to play tracks from Spotify using the Android SDK. I do my authorization as described here https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/. I would like to allow for a functionality to allow the user to search for a song, as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), this is not supported by the Android SDK but is supported by the web API as documented here https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/. The issue is that this request requires an access token. Is it possible to get an access token when using the authorization flow from the SDK, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. In order to use Spotify's Web API you need a valid access token. The guide you linked uses the App Remote SDK’s built-in auth flow. It requests an access token including the `app-remote-control` scope internally. Though I couldn't actually find anything in the reference that allows to retrieve that exact access token.

---

In this case you have to use the [Android Auth library](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/). This guide shows two ways of authentication while the first one which uses either the Spotify client or if not installed a `WebView` fallback is the one they highly recommend. Following this guide at some point you will get a [AuthenticationResponse](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/auth-lib/docs/com/spotify/sdk/android/authentication/AuthenticationResponse.html) object where you can use a method called `getAccessToken()` in order to retrieve an access token you can use with Spotify's Web API later on as seen in the following snippet. It is important to at least include the `app-remote-control` scope as mentioned before. In case you want to fetch user specific data (e.g. playlists) you need to include the corresponding scopes as well.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

  // Check if result comes from the correct activity
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);

    switch (response.getType()) {
      // Response was successful and contains auth token
      case TOKEN:
        // Handle successful response
        String accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
        break;

      // Auth flow returned an error
      case ERROR:
        // Handle error response
        break;

      // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
      default:
        // Handle other cases
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i search for a song with user input and play inside app without user account on spotify but with correct auth key from developer?

Comment: @androidXP did you find the way to search without login? Does Android-API allow to search songs?